# I have a problem with TabContainer control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, controls

It doesnt appear on the screen when I run it..but it does appear in visual studio 2010 in the design view. Also i want to set the tabs from left to right to right to left:

```
          <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="2" 
   Height="584px" Width="739px" AutoPostBack="True" BackColor="#666699" 
   BorderColor="#666699">
          <asp:TabPanel ID="Questions" runat="server" HeaderText="שאלות">

              <ContentTemplate>

                  <asp:GridView runat="server" Height="547px" 
                      style="margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 15px" Width="667px">
                  </asp:GridView>

                    </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:TabPanel>
                <asp:TabPanel ID="Answers" runat="server" HeaderText="תשובות">
              <ContentTemplate>
                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="547px" 
                      style="margin-top: 17px" Width="666px">
                  </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:TabPanel>
                <asp:TabPanel ID="Responses" runat="server" HeaderText="תגובות">
              <ContentTemplate>
                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" Height="547px" 
                      style="margin-top: 21px" Width="666px">
                  </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:TabPanel>
   </asp:TabContainer>
```

Comment: Why are you establishing an absolute position for the header?

Comment: the demostyle is in teh header...they are two separated sections. Brian..to try to move it perhaps

Answer (score 0):

For set tabs right to left add the following style onto the page:

```
.ajax__tab_header
{
     text-align: right;
}
```

But for resolving visibility issue it is not enough information. Do you play with visibility property in code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

Or even better:

```
.ajax__tab_header
{
     direction: rtl;
}
```

that will switch the order of the tabs too. (for rtl languages)